# Measuring the change of angle on any plane

Tags: measurement, gyro

I've been trying to come up with a system to measure the change in angle on any plane. So basically I hold up my electronics board in some kind of angle, click on a button to reset the measurement, and then rotate the board over either it's local x, y or z axis, and then measure the rotated angle.

I've tried to do this with gyros, and use their angular velocity to calculate the angle which has moved. However due to the heavy noise in the gyros, the 'angle random walk' of the measurement is so intense that the measurement is almost unusable.

Given that the system is not attached to anything, what could I use best to accomplish this? (Or is there a way to make the gyros work for this application?)

Comment: Accuracy? Resolution?

Comment: A tenth of a degree would be great.

Comment: How big/heavy is your "any plane"? :) It's real plane or RC model?

Answer (score 3):

You can get very low drift by buying a very good gyro.. for example a ring-laser or fiber-optic gyro, but the cost may be prohibitive for your application (I'm currently working with a triad that costs as much as a decent automobile), and the very good ones tend to have export controls and other associated inconveniences since they have obvious dual-use capability in weapon inertial navigation applications.

If you only want to measure small deviations from horizontal (deviation from the gravity vector), there are interesting clinometer (inclinometer) methods that use electrodes disposed in a dielectric fluid, sort of an electronic 2-D spirit level. Since they're an absolute measurement you can zero them out and they'll not continuously drift (other than the usual 1/f type thermal drift).

Comment: ouch...that's a bit over budget. I was hoping to make something as convenient and simple as a 'level', but then for any angle. If the cost is way too high, then it's not that practical anymore.

Answer (score 2):

0.1° absolute accuracy would be pretty much state of the art. The only non-contact ways I can think of to get to that level involve either radio signals (e.g., GPS interferometry) or optical signals (e.g., a camera pointed at a patterned target).

What kind of environmental constraints and/or size constraints do you have (or can you have) on your device?

Comment: I was hoping to make something as convenient as a level, but then for any angle, not just angles based on the gravity vector.

Comment: I think that the only way to get to that level of accuracy in the price range you're looking for is to use a mechanical system that has a fixed base and an arm of some sort that incorporates one or more shaft encoders. Sort of the angular equivalent of the cheap electronic calipers you can purchase today. Google has lots of hits for "digital protractor", but I take it that's not quite what you're looking for.